# Posting something to website

Tags: python, html

I want to create a program that writes something to text box in html (for example the google search bar). But i don't know how to do that in urllib. This is what it needs to do:
1-Get the page and find the box.
2-Write something to the box.
3-Post it and give results.

I only want a example of how to find box and post it, no full code.

Thanks to everyone from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will describe how to do it with urllib, but below you will find other libraries that I recommend to solve your question.

If you use urllib, you have to look at the form action attribute to reverse-engineer the POST request. Then, with this code, you can replicate that POST:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

*Source of the code: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869977/python-urllib-urllib2-fill-form)*

As I mentioned, there is an easier alternative to urllib for this problem. I personally recommend that you use [RoboBrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) or [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup). They are more straightforward since they will figure out the POST request for you.

An example using RoboBrowser:

```
# Browse to the website
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open('http://website.com/')

# Find the form, write on a text box, and submit it
form = browser.get_form(action='/search')
form['q'].value = 'your text'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

The only issue is that they do not work on all websites, especially in dynamic ones. So, if these solutions do not work, a nice workaround is to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Selenium automates a real browser, so it will load all the dynamic parts of the website (such as the Javascript). The problem is that it is slower that doing your own request, so I recommend using RoboBrowser or MechanicalSoup before trying Selenium.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, i will try this right now :)

Comment: Good luck! If it worked, please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work